# Query for intersection between A and B unless B is empty set in SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to write an SQL query for intersection between A and B *unless* B is empty set. For example:

Table A:

```
| col |
-------
|  1  |
|  2  |
-------
```

Table B:

```
| col |
-------
|  2  |
|  3  |
-------
```

Table B':

```
| col |
-------
-------
```

- For A and B, I expect `2` (take `B` which are also contained in `A`)

  - e.g. `SELECT * FROM A INTERSECT SELECT * FROM B;` or `SELECT A.* from A JOIN B ON a.col = b.col;`
- For A and B', I expect `1` and `2` (take `A` as default if `B` is empty)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Are you intersecting the table columns(a and b) or just a variables?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I clarify the data structure I expect.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : Modified for Postgres.

You can run the standard `INETRSECT` command using both sets to get the standard intersect results. In order to return the non-empty set when on set is empty, `UNION` the `INTERSECT` results, which will be null if a set is missing, against the non-empty set. There needs to be an empty check on the second step or all distinct values will be returned when both sets have values with no intersects `{a,b,c}{x,y,z}`

**Schema (PostgreSQL v14)**

```
CREATE TABLE SetA (SetValue INT);
CREATE TABLE SetB(SetValue INT);

INSERT INTO SetA VALUES(7),(3);
INSERT INTO SetB VALUES(2),(3),(1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT        
    SetValue
FROM
(
    SELECT SetValue FROM
    (
        SELECT SetValue FROM SetA
        UNION 
        SELECT SetValue FROM SetB
    )x
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SetA) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SetB)
        
    UNION
  
    SELECT SetValue FROM SetA
    INTERSECT
    SELECT SetValue FROM SetB 
  
 )x;
```

| setvalue |
| --- |
| 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Thanks, it is very interesting!

Comment: Converted from mssql to postgres as per added tag.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve the issue,

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(20)='{1, 2, 3}'
DECLARE @B VARCHAR(20)='{}'


    SELECT CASE WHEN @B='{}' THEN @A ELSE '{'+STRING_AGG(A.Data,',')+'}' END AS Data 
    FROM (
    
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(Value,'{',''),'}',''))) Data FROM string_split(@A,',')
    INTERSECT
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(Value,'{',''),'}',''))) Data FROM string_split(@B,',')) A
```

Comment: Thanks but your query is hard to understand. Could you please remove unnecessary string operations?

Comment: @okapies, unnecessary  - how could we know? Your presentation of data is very unclear.